# Can I PHP login to same page? Gotta use old auth method

Tags: php, session

I have a page of information pulled from my db, that I want to be able to edit in-place. It's just a page of my fave bookmarks.

i.e. normally, I view the page, but a login in the upper corner changes the page to add controls which I can use to add, edit and delete the data.

I want to know if (and how) I can show the added elements on the same page, depending on whether I have a valid session going.

The one wrinkle I have is that I must use the "old" connection method - my webhost will not support the latest PHP/mysql connection methods, though mysql still requires a long password. (I confess, I don't understand any of this, despite having read about it.)

The upshot is that this is the connection method that **does** work:

```
define('CLIENT_LONG_PASSWORD', 1);
$connection = @mysql_connect(myHost, myUser, myPass, false, CLIENT_LONG_PASSWORD)
or die(mysql_error());
$db  = @mysql_select_db(myDatabase, $connection) or
die(mysql_error());
```

Can someone give me a push in the right direction, or provide a link?

Or wuld it be better to write a whole new page with the controls in-place?

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and are **removed** since **PHP 7**. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: If your host doesn't support PDO or mysqli, you really need to switch hosts.

Comment: Agreed. Well, they support them on a dedicated IP, not on a shared iP.

Comment: So, my question has not been answered. While it would be nice to upgrade, that is not currently on my short-term roadmap. I wish to solve this with the configuarion I have, Can it be done?